# PyTorch torch_sparse installation without CUDA

Tags: python, module, pip, pytorch

I am new in PyTorch and I have faced one issue, namely I cannot get my torch_sparse module properly installed.
In general, I wanted to use module `torch_geometric` - this I have installed. However, when during the execution of the program I keep receiving the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘torch_sparse’ .

I try to intall it, but when I use the command `pip install torch-sparse` in anaconda, I get an error:

UserWarning: CUDA initialization:Found no NVIDIA driver on your system.

My system does not have a CUDA. So how could I install `torch_sparse` module without it?

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards

Rostyslav

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As outlined in in [pytorch_geometric installation instructions](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html#installation-via-binaries) you have to install dependencies first and `torch_geometric` after that.

For PyTorch `1.7.0` and CPU:

```
pip install --no-index torch-scatter -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cpu.html
pip install --no-index torch-sparse -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cpu.html
pip install --no-index torch-cluster -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cpu.html
pip install --no-index torch-spline-conv -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.0+cpu.html
pip install torch-geometric
```

**Please notice `torch-1.7.0+cpu` at the very end of each page**

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply!
Well, I have uninstalled my ``` torch-geometric``` and now I am trying to install ```torch-scatter``` using
```pip install --no-index torch-scatter -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.1.html```
However I receive an error 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch-scatter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch-scatter

even though my PyTorch version is 1.7.1 and I have no cuda. Do you know what is the reason?

Comment: @Rostyslav if you are using anaconda, please install `pip` inside `conda` first using `conda install pip`. After that follow with those commands.

Comment: Sorry, I am using ```pip install --no-index torch-scatter -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.7.1+cpu.html``` as you suggested. But still the same error 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch-scatter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch-scatter

Comment: @Rostyslav make sure that you use Python `3.8`, not `3.9`.

Comment: I use Python 3.8.5

Comment: @Rostyslav https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/ here are available versions. Go with `torch-1.7.0` as in my answer, not in `torch-1.7.1`

Comment: Works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the use of `conda` instead of `pip` very useful. Running the following three commands turned out to be smooth and without errors:

1. conda install -c pyg pytorch-sparse
2. conda install -c pyg pytorch-scatter
3. conda install -c pyg pyg

As far as I understood from the torch-geometric [docs](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/installation.html),we should be fine with these commands on CUDA/CPU.