# pytorch geometric: OSError: Symbol not found

Tags: pytorch

Could anyone please help me with the following error which appears when loading pytorch geometric (installed following [PyTorch torch_sparse installation without CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860764/pytorch-torch-sparse-installation-without-cuda/65861961#65861961))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 8, in <module>
    from models.gat import GATNet
  File "/Users/xxx/yyy/models/gat.py", line 5, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.nn import GATConv
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import torch_geometric.data
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .data import Data
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from torch_sparse import coalesce, SparseTensor
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    f'{library}_{suffix}', [osp.dirname(__file__)]).origin)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 104, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN2at5emptyEN3c108ArrayRefIxEERKNS0_13TensorOptionsENS0_8optionalINS0_12MemoryFormatEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so
  Expected in: /Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
 in /Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_sparse/_convert_cpu.so
```

I tried deleting anaconda, deleting my cache and reinstalling. But nothing seemed to help. It is macOS Catalina.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455890/pytorch-cpu-only-on-osx-fails-with-symbol-not-found solve your problem?